# how to sum values of same id in datagridview?

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to sum values of same id in datagridview and trying to update sql database table. how to do it?

[image]

```vb
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
    If Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value) = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value) Then
        y += Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: If you were to store your data in a `DataTable` and bind that to the grid then you could simply call the `Compute` method of that `DataTable`.

Comment: Please don't submit your question if your code is complete dog's breakfast. Make the effort to help the people whom you want to help you and format your code properly. This site provides a preview for a reason.

Comment: Also, you have provided code but you haven't actually told us what the problem is. How EXACTLY does that code not perform to your expectations? You need to be more specific than that it doesn't produce the desired result too. You need to have debugged the code and tell us EXACTLY how and where the behaviour of the code differs from your expectation.

Comment: What's up with that `If` statement? You're comparing the value in a cell to itself. How can that be useful? This is what happens when you try to write code without knowing what it actually has to do, i.e. not just the end result but the steps to get there. You need to work out the logic involved first and then write code to implement that logic. You'd never have written that code if you had done that because you would never think to yourself that you need to compare a cell to itself.

Answer (score 0):

As you have been already told, the `if` statement you are coding is comparing a cell with itself, which doesn't make sense, because it Will always return `true`.

I'm guessing that you need to compare all cells that share the same `id` and sum the result, but you would need to elaborate the question better, so we can understand what your actuall purpose is.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Dictionary to check and group id with sum values

```
Dim totals As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()

For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim group As String = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("id").Value)
    Dim qty As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("value").Value)

    If totals.ContainsKey(group) = False Then
        totals.Add(group, qty)
    Else
        totals(group) += qty
    End If

Next
```

or use group with LINQ:

```
Dim totals = DataGridView2.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().GroupBy(Function(row) row.Cells("id").Value.ToString()).[Select](Function(g) New With {Key
    .id= g.Key, Key
    .SumValues = g.Sum(Function(row) Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells("value").Value))
})
```